# How to correctly animate elements moving up/down in a set of stacked elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am creating a set of stacked elements where one element could be added on top and the rest will move down. Likewise, an element can be delete and every element beneath this one will slide up. However, I am struggling a bit with the animation part.

I managed to set the animations and the divs slide up and down. However, when the class 'transitionUp' is added (this happens after adding/removing/moving a div), if I add/remove several rows quickly that messes up the animation. If I wait for the transition to finish between actions, then it works fine. I wonder if there is a better way of doing this.

[image]

I created a snippet to explain the problems I am having:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  addMore(i);
}

$('#addMoreBtn').click(function() {
  addMore($('#previewDivContainer').children().length)
});

function moveDivToTop(elm) {
  var index = $(elm).index();
  $('#previewDivContainer').children().slice(0, index).each(function () {
    moveDivDown(this);
  });
  $(elm).css('margin-top', "0px");
  $(elm).prependTo($('#previewDivContainer'))
};

function moveDivUp(index) {
  $('#previewDivContainer').children().slice(index, $('#previewDivContainer').children().length).each(function () {
   $(this).addClass("transitionUp");
   $(this).css('margin-top', parseFloat($(this).css('margin-top')) - $($('#previewDivContainer').children()[0]).height() + "px");
  });
};

function moveDivDown(elm) {
 $(elm).addClass('transitionUp');
 $(elm).css('margin-top', parseFloat($(elm).css('margin-top')) + $($('#previewDivContainer').children()[0]).height() + "px");
};

function removeDiv(elm) {
  var index = $(elm).index();
  console.log(index)
  moveDivUp(index);
  elm.remove();
};

function addMore(index) {
  $('#previewDivContainer').prepend(
    $('<div\>', { class: "previewDiv"}).append(
      $('<span\>', { class: "previewDivName", text: index}),
      $('<span\>', { class: "previewDivMesage", text: `This is ${index}`}),
      $('<div\>').append(
        $('<button\>', {class: "btnUpd", text: "↑"}).click(function () {moveDivToTop($(this).closest('.previewDiv'))}), 
        $('<button\>', {class: "btnDown", text: "X"}).click(function () {removeDiv($(this).closest('.previewDiv'))}),
      )
    )
  )
  moveManyDown(0);
};

function moveManyDown (index) {
  $('#previewDivContainer').children(`:gt(${index})`).each(function() {
    $(this).css('margin-top', parseFloat($(this).css('margin-top')) + $($('#previewDivContainer').children()[0]).height() + "px");
  })
}
```

```css
.previewDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

#previewDivContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.previewDivMesage {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#addMoreBtn {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.transitionUp {
  transition: margin-top 1s; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="previewDivContainer">
</div>

<div id='addMore'>
  <button id='addMoreBtn'>
    Add More
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use timeout?

Comment: @Ermi and set it to whatever the animation duration is? Hmm. I guess so, but I am not very happy setting a timer for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the margin values change during animantion. 
so, solution is to use fixed value when set margin.

The margin is determined by the position of the element. \

```
div 0 -> margin-top: 0
div 1 -> margin-top: (div's height)
div 2 -> margin-top: (div's height) * 2
```

rewrite like this,

```
function moveDivToTop(elm) {
    var index = $(elm).index();
    // append index
    $('#previewDivContainer').children().slice(0, index).each(function (i) {
        moveDivDown(this, i);
    });
    $(elm).css('margin-top', "0px");
    $(elm).prependTo($('#previewDivContainer'))
};

function moveDivDown(elm, idx) {
    const height = $($('#previewDivContainer').children()[0]).height();
    $(elm).addClass('transitionUp');
    $(elm).css('margin-top', height *(idx+1) + "px"); // margin-top set fixed value
};
```

Comment: Thank you @green-21, but I cannot make it work. Could you provide a snippet of this working? I have been trying for a while but it does the same thing.

Comment: Ok. After more testing I started to like your answer a lot more. It seems to be working. I need to do the rest of the functions and see how the whole thing works when many things get added deleted.

Comment: @ehtio oh, I'm truly sorry for checking the alarm late. Also, I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: Your solution was spot on! It's nice when the answer makes the code more readable and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @green-21 for pointing me in the right direction.
I am only writting this to include a full snippet in case it can be useful to somebody reading this.

[image]

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  addMore(i);
}

$('#addMoreBtn').click(function() {
  addMore($('#previewDivContainer').children().length)
});

function moveDivToTop(elm) {
  var index = $(elm).index();
  $(elm).css('margin-top', "0px");
  $(elm).prependTo($('#previewDivContainer'))
  $('#previewDivContainer').children().slice(1, index + 1).each(function() {
    moveDivDown(this);
  });
}

function moveDivUp(index) {
  $('#previewDivContainer').children().slice(index, $('#previewDivContainer').children().length).each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("transitionUp");
    $(this).css('margin-top', $(this).height() * ($(this).index() - 1) + "px");
  });
}

function moveDivDown(elm) {
  var index = $(elm).index();
  $(elm).addClass('transitionUp');
  console.log($(elm).height());
  $(elm).css('margin-top', $(elm).height() * (index) + "px");
}

function removeDiv(elm) {
  var index = $(elm).index();
  console.log(index)
  moveDivUp(index);
  elm.remove();
}

function addMore(index) {
  $('#previewDivContainer').prepend(
    $('<div\>', {
      class: "previewDiv"
    }).append(
      $('<span\>', {
        class: "previewDivName",
        text: index
      }),
      $('<span\>', {
        class: "previewDivMesage",
        text: `This is ${index}`
      }),
      $('<div\>').append(
        $('<button\>', {
          class: "btnUpd",
          text: "↑"
        }).click(function() {
          moveDivToTop($(this).closest('.previewDiv'))
        }),
        $('<button\>', {
          class: "btnDown",
          text: "X"
        }).click(function() {
          removeDiv($(this).closest('.previewDiv'))
        }),
      )
    )
  )
  moveManyDown(0);
}

function moveManyDown(index) {
  $('#previewDivContainer').children(`:gt(${index})`).each(function() {
    moveDivDown(this);
  })
}
```

```css
.previewDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

#previewDivContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.previewDivMesage {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#addMoreBtn {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.transitionUp {
  transition: margin-top 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="previewDivContainer">
</div>

<div id='addMore'>
  <button id='addMoreBtn'>
    Add More
  </button>
</div>
```